# FAILED CONFIGURATION: @BeforeMethod setUp : java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, selenium, testng

I have written the below code which is one of the program in designing a framework and it is giving me this below error everytime. Can some one pls help me in fixing this issue.
"[RemoteTestNG] detected TestNG version 7.0.1 FAILED CONFIGURATION: @BeforeMethod setUp java.lang.NullPointerException"

```
    package com.mercury.qa.testcases;

import org.testng.Assert;
import org.testng.annotations.AfterMethod;
import org.testng.annotations.AfterTest;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeMethod;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeTest;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

import com.mercury.qa.base.TestBase;
import com.mercury.qa.pages.HomePage;
import com.mercury.qa.pages.LoginPage;

public class LoginPageTest extends TestBase {

    LoginPage loginPage;
    HomePage homePage;
    public LoginPageTest() {

        // This super() keyword will call the constructor of the base class which is 'TestBase'
        super();
    }

    @BeforeMethod

    public void setUp() {
        // This will call initialization() method from the base class but initialization() method
        //in the base class contains getProperty() method so to avoid the compiler to throw null pointer 
        //exception we have @Nullabledesigned the above constructor and called the base class constructor 
        //through super() keyword.
        initialization();
        loginPage = new LoginPage();
    }

    @Test(priority = 1)
    public void loginPageTitleTest() {
        String title = loginPage.validateLoginPageTitle();
        Assert.assertEquals(title, "Welcome: Mercury Tours");
    }

    @Test(priority = 2)
    public void mercuryImageLogoTest() {
        boolean flag = loginPage.validateMercuryLogo();
        Assert.assertTrue(flag);
    }

    @Test(priority = 3)
    public void loginTest() {
        //HomePage homePage = new HomePage(); // same as return New HomePage() which is written in LoginPage.java class
        homePage = loginPage.login(prop.getProperty("username"), prop.getProperty("password"));
    }

    @AfterMethod
    public void tearDown() {
        driver.quit();
    }
}
```

and below is the test base class which the above program is extending

```
package com.mercury.qa.base;

import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Properties;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.events.EventFiringWebDriver;

import com.mercury.qa.util.TestUtil;

public class TestBase {


    public static WebDriver driver;
    public static Properties prop;
    public static EventFiringWebDriver e_driver;

    public TestBase(){
        try {
            prop = new Properties();
            FileInputStream ip = new FileInputStream("F:\\Vishal_Offc Work\\Workspace\\"
                    + "FreeMercuryTest\\src\\main\\java\\com\\mercury"
                    + "\\qa\\config\\config.properties");
            prop.load(ip);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }


    public static void initialization(){

        String browserName = prop.getProperty("browser");

        if(browserName.equals("chrome")){
            System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","F:\\Drivers\\chromedriver_win32\\chromedriver.exe");
        }
        else if(browserName.equals("FF")){
            System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver","F:\\Drivers\\geckodriver-v0.26.0-win64\\geckodriver.exe"); 
            driver = new FirefoxDriver(); 
        }

        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        driver.manage().deleteAllCookies();
        driver.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout(TestUtil.PAGE_LOAD_TIMEOUT, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(TestUtil.IMPLICIT_WAIT, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

        driver.get(prop.getProperty("url"));

    }


}
```

below is the console error which I am getting

```
[RemoteTestNG] detected TestNG version 7.0.1
FAILED CONFIGURATION: @BeforeMethod setUp
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.mercury.qa.base.TestBase.initialization(TestBase.java:50)
    at com.mercury.qa.testcases.LoginPageTest.setUp(LoginPageTest.java:31)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:134)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethodConsideringTimeout(MethodInvocationHelper.java:63)
    at org.testng.internal.ConfigInvoker.invokeConfigurationMethod(ConfigInvoker.java:348)
    at org.testng.internal.ConfigInvoker.invokeConfigurations(ConfigInvoker.java:302)
    at org.testng.internal.TestInvoker.runConfigMethods(TestInvoker.java:695)
    at org.testng.internal.TestInvoker.invokeMethod(TestInvoker.java:523)
    at org.testng.internal.TestInvoker.invokeTestMethod(TestInvoker.java:173)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodRunner.runInSequence(MethodRunner.java:46)
    at org.testng.internal.TestInvoker$MethodInvocationAgent.invoke(TestInvoker.java:816)
    at org.testng.internal.TestInvoker.invokeTestMethods(TestInvoker.java:146)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:146)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:128)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1510)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:766)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:587)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:384)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:378)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:337)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:286)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:53)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:96)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1187)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1109)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuites(TestNG.java:1039)
    at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1007)
    at org.testng.remote.AbstractRemoteTestNG.run(AbstractRemoteTestNG.java:115)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:251)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:77)

SKIPPED CONFIGURATION: @AfterMethod tearDown
SKIPPED CONFIGURATION: @BeforeMethod setUp
SKIPPED CONFIGURATION: @AfterMethod tearDown
SKIPPED CONFIGURATION: @BeforeMethod setUp
SKIPPED CONFIGURATION: @AfterMethod tearDown
SKIPPED: loginPageTitleTest
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.mercury.qa.base.TestBase.initialization(TestBase.java:50)
    at com.mercury.qa.testcases.LoginPageTest.setUp(LoginPageTest.java:31)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:134)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethodConsideringTimeout(MethodInvocationHelper.java:63)
    at org.testng.internal.ConfigInvoker.invokeConfigurationMethod(ConfigInvoker.java:348)
    at org.testng.internal.ConfigInvoker.invokeConfigurations(ConfigInvoker.java:302)
    at org.testng.internal.TestInvoker.runConfigMethods(TestInvoker.java:695)
    at org.testng.internal.TestInvoker.invokeMethod(TestInvoker.java:523)
    at org.testng.internal.TestInvoker.invokeTestMethod(TestInvoker.java:173)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodRunner.runInSequence(MethodRunner.java:46)
    at org.testng.internal.TestInvoker$MethodInvocationAgent.invoke(TestInvoker.java:816)
    at org.testng.internal.TestInvoker.invokeTestMethods(TestInvoker.java:146)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:146)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:128)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1510)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:766)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:587)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:384)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:378)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:337)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:286)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:53)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:96)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1187)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1109)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuites(TestNG.java:1039)
    at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1007)
    at org.testng.remote.AbstractRemoteTestNG.run(AbstractRemoteTestNG.java:115)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:251)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:77)

SKIPPED: mercuryImageLogoTest
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.mercury.qa.base.TestBase.initialization(TestBase.java:50)
    at com.mercury.qa.testcases.LoginPageTest.setUp(LoginPageTest.java:31)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:134)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethodConsideringTimeout(MethodInvocationHelper.java:63)
    at org.testng.internal.ConfigInvoker.invokeConfigurationMethod(ConfigInvoker.java:348)
    at org.testng.internal.ConfigInvoker.invokeConfigurations(ConfigInvoker.java:302)
    at org.testng.internal.TestInvoker.runConfigMethods(TestInvoker.java:695)
    at org.testng.internal.TestInvoker.invokeMethod(TestInvoker.java:523)
    at org.testng.internal.TestInvoker.invokeTestMethod(TestInvoker.java:173)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodRunner.runInSequence(MethodRunner.java:46)
    at org.testng.internal.TestInvoker$MethodInvocationAgent.invoke(TestInvoker.java:816)
    at org.testng.internal.TestInvoker.invokeTestMethods(TestInvoker.java:146)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:146)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:128)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1510)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:766)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:587)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:384)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:378)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:337)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:286)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:53)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:96)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1187)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1109)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuites(TestNG.java:1039)
    at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1007)
    at org.testng.remote.AbstractRemoteTestNG.run(AbstractRemoteTestNG.java:115)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:251)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:77)

SKIPPED: loginTest
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.mercury.qa.base.TestBase.initialization(TestBase.java:50)
    at com.mercury.qa.testcases.LoginPageTest.setUp(LoginPageTest.java:31)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:134)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethodConsideringTimeout(MethodInvocationHelper.java:63)
    at org.testng.internal.ConfigInvoker.invokeConfigurationMethod(ConfigInvoker.java:348)
    at org.testng.internal.ConfigInvoker.invokeConfigurations(ConfigInvoker.java:302)
    at org.testng.internal.TestInvoker.runConfigMethods(TestInvoker.java:695)
    at org.testng.internal.TestInvoker.invokeMethod(TestInvoker.java:523)
    at org.testng.internal.TestInvoker.invokeTestMethod(TestInvoker.java:173)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodRunner.runInSequence(MethodRunner.java:46)
    at org.testng.internal.TestInvoker$MethodInvocationAgent.invoke(TestInvoker.java:816)
    at org.testng.internal.TestInvoker.invokeTestMethods(TestInvoker.java:146)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:146)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:128)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1510)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:766)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:587)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:384)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:378)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:337)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:286)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:53)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:96)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1187)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1109)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuites(TestNG.java:1039)
    at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1007)
    at org.testng.remote.AbstractRemoteTestNG.run(AbstractRemoteTestNG.java:115)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:251)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:77)


===============================================
    Default test
    Tests run: 3, Failures: 0, Skips: 3
    Configuration Failures: 1, Skips: 5
===============================================


===============================================
Default suite
Total tests run: 3, Passes: 0, Failures: 0, Skips: 3
Configuration Failures: 1, Skips: 5
===============================================
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow.  Looking just at the code you posted is not enough to say about what's going wrong here. Try to add error stack trace as well. Also, try to show the `initialization()` method of `TestBase` classs in your question.

Comment: What's the line number 50 in  `TestBase` class?? In stackoverflow, we can't see line number. Can you tell that line in comments? Your error stack trace shows you have null pointer exception at line number 50 in `TestBase`.

Comment: Hi, I have given the initialization() method in TestBase() class above. The line no 50 is   driver.manage().window().maximize(); in TestBase() class. Please let me know if you need any more information. Thanks

Comment: If possible try to debug your application..  As line 50: `driver.manage().window().maximize()` is throwing NPE then it means, either `driver` or `driver.manage()` or `driver.manage().window()` is null. 3 possibilities are here.. try to check step wise where exactly you are getting `null`.

Comment: Most probably the cause is that the initialization of `driver` is missing in case browser==chrome (along with other cases different of Firefox).

Comment: @Little Santi..yes you are right. I missed that statement, I have now added the initialization of driver and it worked for me. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the TestBase() class in line no 41. I have missed the driver initialization for chrome although it was added for firefox but not for chrome. I have added the below statement in the if statement and it worked for me.

driver = new ChromeDriver();